# A String can behave differently due to different creation?

Tags: java, string, comparison, equals

*First of all, I searched about this in both S.O. and Google. If you say this is a duplicate of something somewhere, that something is being really hard to reach.*

Well... we know Strings are Objects and must be compared by using equals, right?

Then, please, explain that:

```
String s1 = new String("string");
String s2 = new String("string");
String s3 = "string";

System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));  // true
System.out.println(s1 == s2);       // false

System.out.println(s1 == "string"); // false
System.out.println(s2 == "string"); // false
System.out.println(s3 == "string"); // true
```

Regarding the `== "string"` outputs, why does only the last one prints "true"?

When they're created, they aren't all Strings? Is now my third String the ugly duckling? ...Worse: if I'm working with a foreign String... it may not be the String that I think it is?! (Notice that s3 has `String` before it, not some primitive.)

...I'm pretty sure s3 has an object inside it.

In other words, what's the difference between declaring a String like this:

```
String s1 = new String("string");
```

and another like this:

```
String s3 = "string";
```

?

Comment: Re: "I searched about this in both S.O. and Google": If you add the word `intern` to your searches -- or just look up the Javadoc for `String.intern` -- you'll have more luck.

Comment: Nice. This means I have to know the existence of this `intern` you know, which I didn't know.

Comment: The ***Related*** questions to your right mean you really didn't search hard enough.

Comment: @UndeoV.E.: Yes, I wasn't criticizing. Sometimes it's hard to find an answer that you don't already more-or-less know.

Comment: @EJP Thanks, that helps, but it's hardly a duplicate. Although the OP got to something similar after some EDITs, the main question was the total opposite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `String s1 = new String("string");`, it creates a new `String` object in the memory and holds the reference through `s1`. Similary by `String s2 = new String("string");`, you get another String object reference through `s2`.

`==` operator compares the object references hence `s1 == s2` is false because they are difference string objects.

When you say `String s3 = "string";`, it creates an **String constant literal**  object  in internal pool (**String class maintains internal pool**) and assigns the reference to `s3`.

More details in the specification below:

> > **All literal strings and string-valued constant expressions are interned.** String literals are defined in §3.10.5 of the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5)

Now when you say, `s3=="string"`, `"string"` is referencing the same String object reference as `s3`(Java does the optimization in creating anonymous constant literal so same value literals are not created again). Thus this comparison is resulting into `true`.

This is not the case with `s1` and `s2` as each are referring an explicit String objects in memory.

Comment: Well, Java uses a lot of "ideas" we usually wouldn't imagine it's happening in the background.

Comment: @UndeoV.E. True. It's all done for possible optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will search for hardcoded literals like "string", and replace them with the same reference object.

Your other two objects should return true on `equals()`, but they are different object's at all, because you're using the new operator.

Comment: Re: "if they occure often": Not true. Interning occurs for *all* string literals (and other compile-time constant string expressions), not just ones that occur often. See [§3.10.5 "String Literals" of *The Java Language Specification*, Java SE 7 Edition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5).

Comment: my fault, thanks for that hint!

Answer (score 0):

Some values of `String` type can be *interned*, that is, several instances of `String` having equal value can point to the same object. For such instances `==` will work correctly, although you can't rely on this behavior, unless you called `intern()` explicitly.

You can try following snippet which will always print `true`:

```
    String s1 = new String("a").intern();
    String s2 = "a".intern();

    System.out.println(s1 == s2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you know about SCP(string constant pool) in java. When you create string using new it will create new reference like normal java object... But when you declare like s3  = "string " it will create reference in SCP only once for same value string.It means if you create any other like s5 = "string"  it will point same reference it won't create new reference.
== will check only reference but .equals() method check value. In your program "string" string value already stored in scp area so when you check s3  == "string " its returning true. Its not creating new reference. If you want more clarety post comment...